# I am trying to populate the **task_item** you can see below but I am not getting the result. Nodejs, Expressjs and MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to populate the **task_item** you can see below but I am not getting the result.

```
{
    "msg": "User not exists",
    "cart": {
        "_id": "5ec0c28cf494113aa06c99d9",
        "task_items": [
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "_id": "5ec0c28cf494113aa06c99da",
                **"task_item": "5ebe499d7e657d322c39345f"**
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "_id": "5ec0d018ecc2411cf40bceae",
                **"task_item": "5ebe499d7e657d322c39345f"**
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "_id": "5ec0d4abfac25246689d15a7",
                **"task_item": "5ec0d4a2fac25246689d15a6"**
            }
        ],
        "crreated": "2020-05-17T04:50:20.869Z",
        "user": {
            "_id": "5ebe4d5d440ab504c8a0d128",
            "name": "Ajit",
            "phone": "9668854799",
            "avatar": "//www.gravatar.com/avatar/20c3d59b7049c9ad85cd33e2ebd3151c?s=200&r=pg&d=mm",
            "password": "$2a$10$FdH7QzoqOHnVoLbbm9GaUOLaJbTTqPWzFWeFACkea2NWlrJrFxZ5a",
            "createdAt": "2020-05-15T08:05:49.418Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 2
    }
}
```

**Below is the Cart.js Model**

```
const monngose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = monngose.Schema;

const CartSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    task_items: [{
        task_item: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SubTaskCategoryItem'},
        quantity: { type: Number, default: 1 }

    }],
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number
    },
    item: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'SubTaskCategoryItem'
    },
    crreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
module.exports = monngose.model('Cart', CartSchema);
```

**SubCategoryItem.js** - This is the item model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const SubTaskItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    subtaskItemName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    subtaskItemImage: {
        type: String
    },
    subtaskItemTime: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    subtaskItemPrice: {
        type: String
    },
    subtaskItemStatus: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    subtask: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'SubTask',
        required: true
    },
    createdAT: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("SubTaskCategoryItem", SubTaskItemSchema);
```

Here I am trying to populate - **cart.js** router

```
const express = require('express');
const Cart = require('../../models/admin/Cart');
const checkJwt = require('../../middleware/admin/user_auth');
const TaskItem = require('../../models/admin/SubTaskCategoryItem');

const router = express.Router();


  router.post('/add_cart', checkJwt, (req, res, next) => {
        const product_id = req.query.productId;
        const quantity = req.query.quantity;
        const user = req.user.id;
  router.get('/get_cart', checkJwt, (req, res, next) => {

    Cart.findOne({ user:  req.user.id })
      .populate({
        path: 'user'
      })
     .populate({
       path: 'item'
      })
    .exec((err, cart) => {      
  res.json({
        msg: 'User not exists',
        cart: cart
      });
    })

  })



  module.exports = router;
```

I am trying to populate the **task_item** but I am not able to do. If anyone knows please see this code.